# jQuery navigation drop-down menu not showing... any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently developing a website that contains a drop down navigation menu with jQuery. However I'm having an issue where the drop down isn't displaying on top of the other elements when I hover over the parent link... I think it's pretty obvious that it's a z-index issue but I have been stumped for a while now so any help would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">

<ul>
    <li><a href=\"index.php\">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\">Parent 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#4F4F4F;
    width:100%;
    min-width:910px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
    z-index:10;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    height:auto;
}

.navigation ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 52px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:11;
}

.navigation ul li a {
    display:block;
    height:29px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: cabinmedium;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-top:18px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:11;
}

.navigation ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    display:none;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
    margin-left:-10px;
    background-color:#89c63b;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    z-index:11;
}

.navigation ul ul li {
    display:block;
    background-color:#89c63b;
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:11;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".navigation ul li").hover(function() {

        $(this).find("ul").stop().fadeToggle(400);

    })

});
```

**NOTE:** I included the jQuery just incase but I have tested and it does infact fade in/out the navigation elements as it needs to.

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: well, that can be done with pure css if you don't know it yet.

Comment: i am aware, but im using jQuery for other reasons. thanks for the heads up though @sdcr

Answer (score 0):

'navigation' class will be as like below code without 'overflow-y', 'overflow-x'

```
.navigation {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #4F4F4F;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 910px;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
      z-index: 10;
      /* overflow-y: hidden; */
      /* overflow-x: auto; */
      height: auto;
    }
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kfboj7pj/)

Comment: i require the overflows, any other way of doing this?

Comment: change overflows by ' display:flex ' it will be work as like overflows.